# Django decorator based on user type

Tags: django, django-authentication

i have the following model:

```
class Developer(models.Model):
    COUNTRIES = (
        ('U', 'United States'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='freelancer_user')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=COUNTRIES, default='U')


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='customer_user')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

I have the following view:

```
@login_required
def postjob(request):
    job_form = JobCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/postjob.html', {'job_form': job_form})
```

This works as far as the authentication. But i want only a Customer user to access this view and not a developer. How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator and a test function:

```
@user_passes_test(is_customer)
def postjob(request):
    job_form = JobCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/postjob.html', {'job_form': job_form})
```

Where `is_customer` is something like:

```
def is_customer(user):
    # how do you tell the user is a customer?
    if user.is_staff or user.is_superuser:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: hi. it worked. can we display a message too? something like "you cannot post a job because you are a developer!"

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this but all of them revolves around using the `login_url` parameter to redirect the user to a custom login view or to send the message as a "get" parameter, please check the docs.